# Unable to run ant task for android project before compile

Tags: android, ant

I have andorid project which which I am trying to build with ant. 
The android project needs a jar that is generated elsewhere and I have to copy it to the libs folder via ant task. I understand I can manually copy it and it works, but in my case jars are to be copied via ant.

to generate build.xml I did

```
 android update project --path .
```

I addded this code to build.xml

```
<target name="-pre-compile">
 <copy todir="${jar.libs.dir}">
   <fileset 
     dir="../path-to-another-project/target" 
     includes="*.jar" />
 </copy>
</target>
```

The above code is added just before

```
<import file="custom_rules.xml" optional="true" />
```

The problem:
When I do ant debug it builds with errors. it complains for the classes which are inside the jar. When I do ant debug second time it builds fine with no errors. 
when I observe the libs folder after the first ant run, the jar file is copied in the libs but seems like it is copied after the code is compiled.

Any ideas if there is something wrong with my code and how can I fix it ?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Found the reason why,

class paths which are included as part of Dx are done far before -pre-compile target runs. So at this time it is already too late to do that,

I override -setup target to do the inclusion of jar and then it works fine